# Should I write "I have been teamed up" or "I had been teamed up"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

I want to write a past perfect tense sentence with a word "teamed up". Should I write

> I have been teamed up

OR

> I had been teamed up.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("no research / ELL"). Hi Magreth, it's important to look up a grammar book or a web page on tenses before you ask this kind of question here, as it will often provide the solution. Our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "Be sure to [mention the research you've done](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5043) and what you're still hoping to learn!" For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: "I have been teamed up with Fred, and next week we will start on a new project together."  "I had been teamed up with Fred, but he retired, so now I'm teamed up with Joe."

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect tense for your sentence is

> I HAD been teamed up.

The other sentence

> I HAVE been teamed up.

becomes present perfect.